# Specify form submit data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to submit data via AJAX, but only an empty string reaches the `ActivateUser` Method.

Here is the Markup

```asp
@model String
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Benutzer aktivieren</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="activateresult"></div>
            <div style="display: none" id="activateUserSuccess" class="alert alert-success">Der Benutzer konnte erfolgreich aktiviert werden :)</div>
            <div style="display: none" id="activateUserFailure" class="alert alert-danger">Leider konnte der Benutzer nicht aktiviert werden :(</div>
            <div class="list-group">
                @foreach (var item in @deactivatedUsers) {
                    using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActivateUser", "Settings", new AjaxOptions() {
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        OnSuccess = "activateSuccess(response)",
                        OnFailure = "activateFailure(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)",
                        UpdateTargetId = "activateresult"
                    }, new {
                        @class = "list-group-item"
                    })) {
                    <h4>
                        @item.Username
                        @Html.Hidden("Username")
                    </h4>
                    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="@item.ID" value="Aktivieren" />
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fertig</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActivateUser(string username) {
    try {
        customerModel.ActivateUser(username);
        return new JsonResult() { Data = true };
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return new JsonResult() { Data = false };
    }
}
```

You can the the whole code on [github](https://github.com/DerKnerd/token-creator/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should fill that hidden field using the value from `item.Username`. Also, *I'm not sure*, but I believe that names are case sensitive. So it should be `username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching this:

```
@Html.Hidden("Username")
```

to this:

```
@Html.Hidden("username", item.Username)
```

The parameter to your action is lowercase, and I believe that it is case-sensitive.

Furthermore, that second parameter I am passing in is the `value` parameter. Without that, I believe framework is going to look for a `Username` property on the `Model`. But here you have a username property on `item`. So the framework wouldn't be able to find the username even with the lowercase correction. You need to explicitly pass in the value in this case.

You can verify you're creating the right thing by looking at the generated HTML in your browser. You want to make sure that your input field is actually named `username` and that its value is actually the current user's username.